# Do you actually need a develop branch when using git?

Tags: git, version-control

So I know that basically every git project hast a `master` and a `develop` branch. This works for most of my Salesforce projects except for one. In that project, there are no releases - 99% of the time it's just single patches (basically Jira tickets) that are being deployed one by one. So ... having that `develop` branch seems like total overkill as basically `develop` and `master` should be always in sync.

Do I actually need the `develop` branch if everything that is finished will be deployed and merged to master immediately? If I have two branches - should I just make two pull requests each time? One PR from `feature` to `develop` and then the same from `develop` to `master`?

This doesn't sound right. And it's a lot of extra work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forego the develop branch if you want to, a lot of simple projects do, but you should be prepared to at least create feature branches for the tickets as you work them. This allows you to juggle multiple JIRA tickets without worrying about clobbering your work. It also makes it easier to track down bugs. For the record, I have a hobby project I'm working on right now, that's just me, and I still use feature branches. I'm not taking any unnecessary risks, and I would advise you not to, either.

Comment: I very much agree. I would still always do feature branches. Just maybe no `develop` branch.

Answer (score 1):

I use branching to segment my code into logical buckets. So I don't have one feature or development branch I have lots of branches. Each branch gets it's own pull request because of peer review/feedback. I deploy from master so everything gets merged into master that is ready for deployment. That way if there are branches that are not ready for deployment they can hang around for the next time I deploy.

I can see if you deploy every time a feature is done this is over kill, but if you move to a process that you have a deploy at a certain time this process makes more sense.

The great thing about git is you can do what ever works for your use case. So if merging on top of master suits your needs just do that. Having the understanding of using branching can't hurt either.